# LINQ to XML exception when there is no summary node present

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have been working with LINQ to XML and have been stuck with an issue. I would really appreciate any help. I am new to LINQ to XML, but I found it easy to work with.

I have two different syndication feeds that I aggregate to one single syndication feed using Union. The final syndication feed contains 10 items.

I am trying to write the syndication feed to an XML file using XDocument and XElement. I have been able to do that successfully for the most part. But, some of the items in the feed do not have a description as a node element. When I get to the items that do not have this node element I am getting an Exception as I don’t have a description node for one of the items. How can I check the items to see if there is a node called description before I start writing the XML file? If the item does not contain the description node how could I populate it with a default value? Could you please suggest me any solution? Thank you for all your time!

```
SyndicationFeed combinedfeed = new SyndicationFeed(newFeed1.Items.Union(newFeed2.Items).OrderByDescending(u => u.PublishDate));

//save the filtered xml file to a folder
XDocument filteredxmlfile = new XDocument(
             new XDeclaration("2.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
             new XElement("channel",
             from filteredlist in combinedfeed.Items
             select new XElement("item",
                  new XElement("title", filteredlist.Title.Text),
                  new XElement("source", FormatContent(filteredlist.Links[0].Uri.ToString())[0]),
                  new XElement("url", FormatContent(filteredlist.Links[0].Uri.ToString())[1]),
                  new XElement("pubdate", filteredlist.PublishDate.ToString("r")),
                  new XElement("date",filteredlist.PublishDate.Date.ToShortDateString()),
// I get an exception here as the summary/ description node is not present for all the items in the syndication feed
new XElement("date",filteredlist.Summary.Text)
                  )));
string savexmlpath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilteredFolder"]) + "sorted.xml";
filteredxmlfile.Save(savexmlpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for `null`:

```
new XElement("date",filteredlist.Summary !=null ? filteredlist.Summary.Text : "default summary")
```

Comment: Hello BorkenGlass,
Thank you for your response. I used the code you have provided me above, but it gives me a object null reference exception. So, I changed it as:
new XElement("description", filteredlist.Summary.Text != null ? filteredlist.Summary.Text : "default summary")
When I do this it is not even creating this node element in the xml file. NO exception nothing.I am not sure but I think I need to way to check if the  description node exists in each of the syndication feed items before I start writing the xml file. Thank you for your time!